# VBScript. Error on data set return

Tags: oop, asp-classic, vbscript, data-access-layer

I don't have any experience programming with `VBScript` and I'd like to use some `OOP` approach. If you'll look at my code below, you will see that I'm trying to create DB access class with a set of methods, that returns data sets. Have no idea why, but receiving error:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01c2'

Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

/TrashCan/library/BLL/CreditBLLClass.asp, line 18
```

I have an `.asp` page:

```
<body>
    <!-- #INCLUDE FILE="library\BLL\CreditBLLClass.asp" -->
    <%             
        Dim creditBLL
        Dim reader
        creditBLL = new CreditBLLClass

            reader = creditBLL.GetData() 
            If reader.EOF = False Then
                Do While reader.EOF = False
                    Response.Write(reader.Fields("a").Value)
                    reader.MoveNext
                Loop    
            End If
    %>
</body>
```

CreditBLLClass.asp:

```
<!-- #INCLUDE FILE="DatabaseConnectionClass.asp" -->
<%
Class CreditBLLClass
    'Private variables
    Dim connection

    Public Default Function Init()
        Set Init = Me
      End Function

    Public Function GetData ()
        connection = new DatabaseConnectionClass
        GetData = connection.DBGetRecords("select a from b")
    End Function
End Class

%>
```

And database connection class

```
<% 

Class DatabaseConnectionClass

'Private variables
dim pConnection

Public Default Function Init()

    Set Init = Me
  End Function

Public Function DBGetRecords ( sSQL )

    Set pConnection = Server.CreateObject( "ADODB.Connection" )
    With pConnection
            .ConnectionString = "string"
            .Open
         End With
        DBGetRecords = pConnection.Execute ( sSQL )
End Function

End Class

%>
```

Please tell me what am I doing wrong? Maybe there is a common approach of how to build data access layer?

Comment: What are those `Init` methods doing?

Comment: Remember that VBScript was not made for OOP style programming. Though organizing your code in classes is possible and not a bad practice, don't force OOP on VBScript too much. You will run into problems / performance issues later on.

Comment: can see that you're right... but before migrate web site to APS.NET have to refactor code somehow or it will take ages...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is in the `invalid property assignment` part of the error.

From your code:

```
connection = new DatabaseConnectionClass
GetData = connection.DBGetRecords("select a from b")
```

You have to use `Set` when using objects.

Change it to this:

```
Set connection = new DatabaseConnectionClass
Set GetData = connection.DBGetRecords("select a from b")
```